# Way to work with bits. Bitbuffer. Android

Tags: java, android, bit-manipulation, nio

I use ByteBuffer. I need to get a buffer, shift by a number of bits.

Now I perform this conversion, extracting int from the buffer and apply the shifts and masks. Is there a more versatile way to work with the bits? Bitbuffer? Guava does not contain the necessary methods by accident? Android support is needed.

ByteBuffer contain:

```
[41 8A 25 E7 B8 9C 0C 1E ...]
```

Need:

```
[5E 7B 89 C0 C1 ...]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that, if you're shifting the entire string, you can keep a "virtual" shift count somewhere, and only apply it when needed.  (I can't recall any really good bitstring manipulation ops in any language other than APL and a few specialized digital simulation languages.)